# Source of Predefined Function-numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

> Write a Python function matrixflip(m,d) that takes as input a two-dimensional matrix m
> and a direction d, where d is either 'h' or 'v'. If d == 'h', the function should return the
> matrix flipped horizontally. If d == 'v', the function should return the matrix flipped
> vertically. For any other value of d, the function should return m unchanged. In all cases,
> the argument m should remain undisturbed by the function

Code:

```
import numpy as np
def matrixflip(m,d):
    m=np.array(m)
    if d=='h':
        m=np.flip(m,axis=1)
        return m

    if d=='v':
        m=np.flip(m,axis=0)
        return m

myl = [[1,2],[3,4]]

print (matrixflip(matrixflip(myl,'h'),'v'))
```

intended output

```
[[4, 3], [2, 1]]
```

The Code works just fine. But what if I want not to use NumPy's `flip` predefined function or suppose I am using an online compiler. How will it be accomplished in the code?

Comment: You write your own code that reverses `m` in the `v` case, or reverses each element of the list in the `h` case. You can use the `reversed()` function to return a reversed copy of a list.

Comment: That's why I want to know that how numpy's flip function works. you know what I mean!

Comment: Much of numpy is written in C so it can use hardware acceleration. But you don't need numpy for this, you can just use ordinary list operations. All it's doing is reversing lists.

Comment: If you dont mind can you please tell me how to reverse list on a vertical axis.

Comment: `list(reversed(m))` will reverse on the vertical axis.

Comment: it give me error "<list_reverseiterator object at 0x7f2eadf05a90>"

Comment: That's not an error, it's a reverse iterator object. But when you call `list()` it should return a list of the contents.

Answer (score 0):

In the `numpy` docs, functions like this have `[source]` like.  That takes you the source in `github`.  If working with `ipython`, `??` displays code.

`flip` basically does a -1 step slice.  The complication comes in choosing which axis.

```
m[::-1]
m[:,::-1]
```